# WARNING: failed to start git_daemon

Tags: freebsd, git

I follow this http://bin63.com/how-to-setup-a-git-repository-on-freebsd tutorial to the letter and edit:

```
/etc/rc.conf
```

with:

```
git_daemon_enable="YES"
git_daemon_directory="/git"
#git_daemon_flags="--syslog --base-path=/git --export-all"
git_daemon_flags="--syslog --export-all"
```

Upon

```
# /usr/local/etc/rc.d/git_daemon start
Starting git_daemon.
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/git_daemon: WARNING: failed to start git_daemon
```

Moreover the boot process hangs at "Starting git_daemon". I pressed ctrl+c and then it finished booting.

```
# service git_daemon start
Starting git_daemon.
```

Pauses indefinately...

```
^C
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/git_daemon: WARNING: failed to start git_daemon
```

And finally

```
# tail /var/log/messages
May  3 14:06:53 web root: /etc/rc: WARNING: failed to start git_daemon
```

Doesn't reveal anything either? I have full root access to my FreeBSD box.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the `git_daemon_flags` that are suggested by the blog are a bit wrong. They cause the git daemon to run in the foreground which causes the boot process to hang.

If you use the following line, you should be able to continue with the tutorial:

`--syslog --base-path=/git --export-all --reuseaddr --detach`